# Requests.content not matching with Chrome inspect element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using BeautifulSoup and Requests to scrape allrecipes user data.

When inspecting the HTML code I find that the data I want is contained within

```
<article class="profile-review-card">
```

However when I use the following code

```
URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/cook/2010/reviews/'
response = requests.get(URL ).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
X = soup.find_all('article', class_ = "profile-review-card"  )
```

While soup and response are full of html, X is empty.  I've looked through and there are some inconsistencies between what I see with inspect element and requests.get(URL).content, what is going on?

[What Chrome inspect shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VtgG.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's loaded using Ajax/javascript. Requests library doesn't handle that, you'll need to use something that can execute these scripts and get the dom. There are various options, I'll list a couple to get you started.

- [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)
- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Selenium is working out great.  In the future how can I recognize websites are being loaded with Ajax/javascript?