# scraping constantly changing numbers off of csgocrash.com with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the values of the crash numbers off of csgocrash.com, but beautifulsoup can't seem to load the whole webpage. Is this because it doesn't load until after it says game loading..? And how would I fix that. Once I can navigate through to the history tab of the website in beautifulsoup I think I will be able to accomplish my goal.

Comment: at a guess the website is populated via js ... so you will need something that actually causes that action to happen... something like selenium or ghost.js is usually the solution

Comment: @Keatinge when the website loads it says game loading.. and then if you click the history tab it shows a list of numbers and I just want to constantly find the top number, but when using beautifulsoup it doesn't show most of the site.

Comment: Open the page in your browser and view the source. It's all loaded via ajax. You'll need something that can run and load javascript. Have a look over here for some python libraries to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/a/36855247/1585957.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?